Connect Sybase SQL Anywhere to DBeaver with ODBC
I have a third-party application running on a Windows server and I need to access its database, they run a Sybase SQL Anywhere server and so far I've been able to configure the ODBC on my local machine to access it through VPN and then make some test queries with python.
What I'm having trouble with is using DBeaver to create said connection using the ODBC, so I can have a clearer view of the tables since I'll need to poke around to understand its structure. How can I achieve that, or if it's not possible with DBeaver (Community Edition) is there another similar tool I can use?
Sybase SQL Anywhere can only be accessed with ODBC or I can create the connection another way that works with DBeaver?
Sorry if the question is not clear or I said something wrong, I'm a noob with database configs stuff. And thank you for the help!

DBeaver give you a list of Database connection ready to use.
The type of connection you are looking for could probably be one of these:

or this

